# Having issues in H2 Database may be already in use

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, h2

I am trying to run application with H2database and Spring-boot. Every time when i redeploy my application in stand alone tomcat. It ends up with saying and build failed:

```
Database may be already in use: "/root/NCRWalmart/walmart-pos-wits-common-configuration/src/main/wits_orch.mv.db". Possible solutions: close all other connection(s); use the server mode [90020-182]
```

I pass through offical site of H2databse and tried different solutions but nothing is working for me. 
I tried to use following URL in my properties file:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:${spring.config.location}/wits_orch;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=true;FILE_LOCK=SOCKET;
```

Any Solution ?

Answer (score 0):

You probably have another process that runs the same H2-instance at the same time.
Try something like `ps -ef | grep h2`, it will show you all processes that using h2*.jar

Comment: Please format your code properly by replacing quotes with backticks(`).